# Using Electron with Angular 2 for both a web and a desktop app

Tags: angular, electron

Are there any blogs/articles on getting started with creating an Electron app using Angular 2 with the goal of creating both a web and a windows app? Eventually, I'll need to be able to create a mobile app as well (I am assuming I'll need to use Ionic 2 for this?)

I am familiar with Angular 2 from the web app development standpoint. How do I setup the architecture to support web/desktop and eventually a mobile app?

As an Electron newbie, any feedback on how to get started/tips/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following blogs
http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=806

http://electron.rocks/angular2-electron/

Also for including nativescript & making a mobile app, there's a wonderful package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ng2-magic

There's one seed template too combining all
https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced , but it doesnt support Angular CLI

Answer (score 0):

For your angular  quick start project, just add these in package.json:

1. add "main": "main.js" at top,
2. add run electron inside script -> start
3. of course add electron in devDependencies
4. Add file [main.js](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/) as electron quick-start

And then you "npm install" and "npm start"

Easy!!!

```
{
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"electron .\" ",
         :
     },
   :
  "devDependencies": {
       :
      "electron": "1.6.2"
   }
 }
```

For full detail see here : [here](https://github.com/Longfld/Angular4Electron)